# Check if number in numpy array is within range specified in another array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

Data

```
a = np.array([[0.5,1,50],[0.5,1,30]])
b = np.array([[0.40,0.60],[0.75,2.0],[40,70]])
```

Expected results:

```
TRUE
FALSE
```

If I only had few rows, a stupid way to do it would be:

```
if b[0][0] <= a[0][0] <=  b[0][1] and b[1][0] <= a[0][1] <=  b[1][1] and b[2][0] <= a[0][2] <=  b[2][1]:
    print("its b!!")
```

Comment: How about flattening the array b, taking min and max of b; and check if the number from a lies inside [min_b, max_b]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
result = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: all((x > b.T[0]) & (x < b.T[-1])), 1, a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
array([ True, False])
```